# How to generate UUID based on historical time?

Tags: php, uuid

I'm using the https://github.com/ramsey/uuid library to generate UUIDs (time based v1 UUID).

How can I generate a UUID from this library using a historical time rather than the current time?

I have a feeling it has something to do with the `FixedTimeProvider` class and something like the below but not sure how to get it to work.

```
$uuidFactory = new \Ramsey\Uuid\UuidFactory();
$uuidFactory->setTimeGenerator(new \Ramsey\Uuid\Generator\DefaultTimeGenerator(
    new \MyVendor\Uuid\NodeProvider(),
    new \MyVendor\Uuid\TimeConverter(),
    new \MyVendor\Uuid\TimeProvider()
));
\Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::setFactory($uuidFactory);

$uuid = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid1();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2017-01-01 12:00:00');
$startTimeProvider = new FixedTimeProvider([
        'sec' => $timestamp,
        'usec' => 0,
    ]);
$startTimeFeatureSet = new FeatureSet();
$startTimeFeatureSet->setTimeProvider($startTimeProvider);
$factory = new UuidFactory($startTimeFeatureSet);
Uuid::setFactory($factory);
echo Uuid::uuid1()->toString();
```

You can test the timestamp of the UUID generated here: https://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen